# Always Resolving dependencies... (3:32.0s)

Tags: flutter, dart

How to fix it? I have a hint that it's because of my network because I tried to connect to the hotspot of my mobile phone, the dependencies are easily resolved, but when I connect to our wifi, it doesn't work like it's always resolving dependencies.

flutter pub upgrade

Resolving dependencies... (43.4s)Terminate batch job (Y/N)? n

PS C:\Users\ASUS\StudioProjects\final_project> flutter pub upgrade

Resolving dependencies... (4:39.2s)

I tried flutter clean but nothing happened, it works when I connect to my phone's hotspot, but when I connect to our wifi, it doesn't always resolve dependencies like it never ends, even though our network is faster.

Answer (score 0):

That is very likely to be due to a firewall or a similar security solution blocking the download of the artifacts.

Either ask the network admins for help in unblocking it or use a [VPN](https://www.kaspersky.com/resource-center/definitions/what-is-a-vpn).